# Doctrine classes, can I add custom functions?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm having a difficult time finding if I can add custom functions to doctrine classes.

Lets say I have

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Map
 */
class Map
{
     /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
     /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

In my classes I would like some custom functions that return values that do not per se need to be stored in databse but merely provide a checking of certain values functionality.

For examply I would like to add a function isAboveTen();

```
function isAboveTen()
   {
   return this->id > 10;
   }
```

Can I just go ahead and  do this or do I need to define them as a special field in the xml file or annotations?

Comment: I am considering that, but i'd rather be sure that i dont have to add some annotations/xml etc so I dont mess up the entity manager

Comment: You don't have to add anything to the Doctrine's configuration. Entity classes are intented to represent the raw data (DTOs) and provide some basic/simply logic related to this data.

Comment: ok. So if I add my own custom logic to extra functions to the doctrine generated classes it wont mess up stuff

Comment: It won't. Just keep in mind that entites are not meant for any sort of heavy logic, just the simpliest stuff like `this->id > 10`.

Comment: @Crozin is absolutely correct about Doctrine 2 ignoring any extra methods or attributes.  Not so sure about the "heavy logic" comment.  There is a design approach called Domain Driven Design where you do want to put as much business logic as you can in your entities.  Doctrine 2 really does not care.

Comment: @Cerad Heavy logic is meant for [Custom Repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Comment: @sjagr - Not necessarily.  Search for some articles on anemic domain models vs rich domain models.  I agree that using anemic domain models is far more common especially with php applications.  But rich models have their place and are kind of fun to design especially when your application moves beyond the crud stage.  Completely off topic of course but there is a stackoverflow tag called 'Domain Driven Design'.

Comment: @Cerad Interesting, thank you!

Comment: @Cerad even in case of DDD you don't want to put too much logic into a single class (entity) as it could easily lead to break of [single responsibility princlple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You'll usually create other classes that works on/with entities.

Comment: I get the point. The only things i wantvto add are some testing functions so i can just  call those and add some restriction testing(for example placement outside map redtrictions) nothing heavy but more to prevent unnessary code repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely add functions working on simple member types, Doctrine will ignore them if you do not add any annotations.

The question whether you should avoid doing this depends on your overall architecture and coding guidelines. As mentioned in the comments both flavors with logic possibly inside vs outside the entities exist.

**However**, you should keep in mind that:

> All persistent properties/field of any entity class should always be private or protected, otherwise lazy-loading might not work as expected. In case you serialize entities (for example Session) properties should be protected (See Serialize section below).

Which is described in the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#entities). Since you are accessing these members inside your class, magic methods like [__get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) will not be called.